# Code Sign with SHA1 and SHA256 Simultaneously (MSBuild SignFile)

Tags: msbuild, code-signing

I'm able to sign .NET assemblies with SHA1 and SHA256 at the same time using signtool.exe ([this link](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=INFO2274&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US) helped me greatly), but I would like to use SignFile task in MSBuild. As far as I understand, SignFile task uses signtool.exe, but when I see the [reference of SignFile in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164304.aspx), there are much less options than signtool.exe and I am not able to sign an assembly with both SHA1 and SHA256 so far.

Obviously I could just use Exec task to execute signtool.exe and be done with it, but I still would like to explore the option of using SignFile as the call would look much cleaner.

Please let me know if you have any information on this.

TIA